# How do I switch from Portupgrade to Portmaster?

Tags: freebsd, ports

I've given a FreeBSD to run a webserver and I always use Portmaster, but it's been installed with Portupgrade.

Is there any problem if I simply start using Portmaster?

Comment: Belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portupgrade and portmaster are interchangeable. You can safely use them together on one box, since they are separated from ports database.